# What are the FAA regulations on grass airstrips?

Tags: faa-regulations, runways, grass-field

What are the FAA regulations on grass airstrips like grass height, lighting, necessary aircraft equipment, and the like?

Comment: If you're asking where to find these regs, I think this question is entirely on topic.  If you're asking for them all to be listed here, I think the question is too broad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went poking around the FAA [Regulatory and Guidance Library](http://rgl.faa.gov) until I found [FAR 139.307](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library%5CrgFAR.nsf/0/C4BECA5E3994416C86256EBB005C3431?OpenDocument), which states:

> Sec. 139.307
>
> Unpaved areas.
>
> (a) In a manner authorized by the Administrator, each certificate
>   holder [must] maintain and promptly repair the surface of each gravel,
>   turf, or other unpaved runway, taxiway, or loading ramp and parking
>   area on the airport that is available for air carrier use as follows:
>
> ...
>
> **(b) FAA Advisory Circulars contain methods and procedures for the maintenance and configuration of unpaved areas that are acceptable to the Administrator.**

So I went looking for those advisory circulars.  There are probably more that I haven't found, but [AC 150/5300-13A - Airport Design](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5300-13A-chg1-interactive-201705.pdf) beginning at page 82 seems to have the sort of thing you're looking for.