# What is required for repeated use of an unimproved area for *repeated* aircraft operations?

Tags: faa-regulations, grass-field

My friend and I were talking about their new house with 7 acres in rural Massachusetts. Since I'm always shopping for excuses to log hours, I half=jokingly talked about coming out to visit if they could find a length of level grass long enough. (They assured me they could.)

This got me thinking: If they were going to build a proper turf strip out there they'd need to do a bunch of paperwork and get approvals from local entities, [the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/airports/central/engineering/part157/), and MassDOT.

All of the language therein, however, seems to be focused around building, changing, modifying, or abandoning *airports*.

If they never strike the earth, is there any reason to expect them to get into trouble if I fly in and out of their backyard a few times a year?

How far can you go towards facilitating bush planes flying in and out of somewhere before you need to file paperwork?

Comment: From [What are the FAA regulations on grass airstrips?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23578/14897), the quotation only concerns fields used by "air carriers". But [Can I land a plane in a field?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7687/14897) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @GdD It does not. I know I can land there. But there's a difference between landing there once, and making repeated trips in and out.

Comment: No, there isn't any difference between landing there once and making repeated trips @WilliamWalkerIII, at least from an FAA point of view.

Comment: Mongo's answer in the dupe question addresses the "repeated" aspect pretty clearly, so voting to close as dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FAA doesn’t care how often private aircraft use a private field. It is completely optional to register it as an airport, though there are substantial protections if you do that make it worth filing the paperwork.

However, state/local laws vary wildly; in some places, you can’t legally land somewhere *even once* without it being a registered airport, while others don’t care if you do it every day. So, consult an aviation attorney for details on your specific location.